# Change selectionbox color to match wallpaper

Tags: themes, desktop-background, colors

[Selectionbox color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utSjq.png)

As you see in the image the box is brown. The color is from the applications theme, which means that it will always be brown. Is there  a way, to make this selection color match the wallpaper? So If my wallpaper is purple, it will turn purple.

Info: Ubuntu 19 Gnome

Comment: Mention the distro, its version and your desktop environment.

Comment: okay i have done that